# PHP JSON Request

Tags: php, json, api

Hi I am trying to make JSON Request to a API but I am not sure how to as I have never worked on something similar ever before. I would really appreciate if someone can help me please.

Below is the request that I need to make:

request payload:

```
{
    "sessionId": "1234567890",
    "availabilityRequest": {
        "checkInDate": "29042014",
        "checkOutDate": "",
        "noRooms": 1,
        "noNights": 1,
        "userType": "leisure",
        "rateType": "standard",
        "roomPreference": [
            {
                "noAdult": 1,
                "noChild": 0
            }
        ],
        "siteCode": [
            "GB0758",
            "GB0746",
            "GB0738",
            "GB0755",
            "GB0742"
        ],
        "includeDisabled": "F"
    }
}
```

This is what I have done but I am getting error `Array ( [error] => Array ( [code] => 4007 [message] => Invalid JSON POST data (unable to decode): ) )`

```
       $postData = '{
                "sessionId":"1234567890",
                "availabilityRequest":
                {
                    "checkInDate": "29042014",
                    "checkOutDate": "",
                    "noRooms": 1,
                    "noNights": 1,
                    "userType": "leisure",
                    "rateType": "standard",
                    "roomPreference": 
                        [
                            { "noAdult":1, "noChild":0 }
                        ],
                    "siteCode": 
                        [
                        "GB0758","GB0746","GB0738","GB0755","GB0742"
                        ],
                    "includeDisabled":"F"
                }
            }';

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        // Send the request
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        // Check for errors
        if($response === FALSE){
            die(curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Decode the response
        $responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);

        // Print the date from the response
        print_r($responseData);
```

I would be really grateful is someone can help me please. Thank you

Comment: What does your `$postData` looks like.

Comment: I have edited the post which shows what my $postData looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really test this because I have no URL to test it with, but you can try to set a header.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postData)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. Validate it using a tool such as http://jsonlint.com/

You should add an other } to the end to close it. Then you will have a valid JSON.

Comment: Json is valid only in the question the last bracket is not included in the code area.

Comment: Why a negative point for the effort of testing and finding an error?